# Slow file parsing with regex

Tags: regex, performance, haskell

just tried to rewrite trivial file parser from pythonto haskell but found it painfully slow (about 15 times slower on the same machine). Code compiled with ghc -O2.

The goal is to count number of lines where regular expression matches.
The sample text file is huge (several GiBs).

Here is the code:

```
import Text.Regex.Posix
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC

filename = "sample.dat"

mcount' :: String -> [BS.ByteString] -> Int
mcount' sample file = foldr (\e acc -> if e =~ sample then acc+1 else acc) 0 file

main = do
    fcnt <- fmap BC.lines $ BS.readFile filename
    print $ mcount' "myregex" fcnt
```

How can I (significantly) improve the performance ?

Comment: Switch from `foldr` to `foldl'`. Possibly compiling the regex will help. I'm not putting this as an answer because I haven't actually profiled it.

Comment: @DanielWagner You don't need to profile that. The question is only _how much_ that will gain.

Comment: Oh, and for a huge text file, you **absolutely** ought to use **`Data.ByteString.Lazy[.Char8]`**. You don't want the entire multi-GB file in memory at once if it needn't be.

Comment: Isn't readFile will read the entire file first. Will it gain to read file lazily ?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer> I did changed imports to lazy version of ByteString and Char8 but there is no performance gain.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner> **Switching `foldr` to `foldl'` did the job !** Just trying to understand the effect of strictness of foldl' in this case.

Comment: @DavidUnric The `foldl'` is the most important piece. I don't know how the regex library works, but compiling the regex in `mcount'` could well yield another significant speedup. The lazy `ByteString`s thing would yield a good speedup if the file is larger than or almost as large as your RAM, not so much if your RAM is much larger (and nothing else on your machine needs a lot of memory), the point is reducing the memory usage, but that also only works with the `foldl'`, so that the lines can be garbage collected because they're immediately used.

Comment: As a side note (that will probably perform worse on huge files): Using an `Int` return value on regex matching shows the number of successful matches. For example, `"example" =~ "e" :: Int` evaluates to `2`. If your file is shorter, you could use this to omit the fold entirely (but the regex would grow a little).

Comment: @DanielFischer The effect of "compiling" regex with `myre = mkRegex sample` and using in foldl' is negligible. Even tried `compile` and `execute` from `Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString.Lazy` but it taints function with IO with performance drop in an addition, probably due to many IO actions - matching & accumulator updating. Also slower with foldl' replaced with Control.Monad.foldM .

Comment: Are regexes really necessary for your problem? (Google regex now you have two problems) The parsec library is easy, clean, efficient and type safe.

Comment: Daniel or Daniel, do you fancy writing it all up as an answer to get it out of the unanswered list?

Comment: Willing to mark Daniel Fisher's answer as the correct one :)

Comment: The Text.Regex.Posix wraps your "system" regex library, which is probably not fast at all (unlike python).  You might try one of the Haskell libraries that wrap PCRE instead.

Comment: I tried Chris K's advice for the heck of it; Text.Regex.PCRE took six seconds to manage 20 million lines, while Text.Regex.Posix took a half-minute.

Comment: @DanielWagner - Could you please post an answer to this question, so that it won't be listed as "unanswered" and so that you can get the redit for that answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important thing seems to be switching from `foldr` to `foldl'`. There are half a dozen other useful optimizations, but that should already make a significant improvement. As a general rule of thumb:

- Use `foldr` when the function you're folding is short-circuiting or uses guarded recursion.
- Use `foldl'` otherwise.
- Don't use `foldl` at all.